# SOA Release management strategy

Tags: release, soa

Currently I have been asked to propose an automated release management solution for a large oracle SOA project. All code is stored on SVN repository and it would be nice if I could suggest something that would build, deploy, run test cases and produced reports for all projects on trunk. I know that I could do that by creating ant or maven scripts, but I would like to know if there is an open source alternative that handles all these complex stuff, without the need of so much coding.

Comment: You should look for continuous integration software such as Jenkins, Hudson, TeamCity or CruiseControl.

Comment: Something else that you could look at (but which will of course require some investment :/ ), is the [Savara](http://www.jboss.org/savara) project, which is about building testable (SOA) architectures.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your requirements are. Are you looking to run tests on your production server?

Or, are you looking for a continuous integration server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)? Jenkins can run your unit tests every time you do a commit and send you a nice email if you fail any tests. You should only deploy *after* Jenkins says it is safe to do so. Note, there are other CI systems out there. I happen to use Jenkins at work.

This doesn't actually handle deploying and launching your updated service, but it's probably one step in the sequence.